# snapshot testing React connected component with PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a Component in my React App that is connected by `react-redux` with two props

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { createNewPlayer } from "../actions/AllActions";
class HomePage extends React.Component {...}
HomePage.propTypes = {
  createNewPlayer: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};
export default connect(null,{ createNewPlayer })(HomePage);
```

at index.js I have `ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}> ...)`

and App.js
`const App = () => (<Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />);export default App`;

for snapshot testing the HomePage I using `Jest` and `Enzyme` I have written

```
import React from "react";    
import toJSON from "enzyme-to-json";    
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import HomePage from "../components/HomePage";

test("should render the HomePage Component", () => {
  const props = { createNewPlayer: jest.fn(), push: jest.fn() };
  const wrapper = mount(shallow(<HomePage {...props} />));
  expect(toJSON(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

where I get the Error

```
 Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(HomePage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(HomePage)".
```

how should I snapshot test a connected component with proptype

Answer (score 1):

You should not tested connected component. We want to test unconnected version because we want to be able to provide a set of dynamic props. props are data. in testing world, you should create a /fixture directory inside /tests directory. You should keep your baseline data or dummy data inside that directory and then export it. Or you can create your data inside the test file but it will make mess.

```
export class HomePage extends React.Component {...}
```

in testing file

```
import React from "react";    
import toJSON from "enzyme-to-json";    
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import {HomePage} from "../components/HomePage";
import props from "../fixtures/createNewPlayer" //in here you should put your data

test("should render the HomePage Component", () => {
  //const props = { createNewPlayer:jest.fn(), push: jest.fn(); IMPORTED ALREADY
  const wrapper = mount(shallow(<HomePage {...props} />));
  expect(toJSON(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your sample test, it doesn't look like you're trying to test the entire integration from `App` down since you only reference `HomePage` in your test. As such, you can export the class for testing in addition to the default connect export. As such, your tests will use `import { HomePage } from '...';` while your other components will use the default `import HomePage from '...';`